# CupertinoPageRouter slides from the left

Tags: flutter

The CupertinoPageRouter transition is from left to right, how do I reverse the transition?

```
onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageTwo()),
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap parent screen in a `Directionality` widget with `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl`